# Unbound value Mirage.load when executing make depend

Tags: ocaml, unikernel, mirage

I'm trying to compile and build this simple Unikernel project https://github.com/MagnusS/mirage-stats-demo under Ubuntu 14.04 with latest versions of OCaml, OPAM and related packages, but when I execute the command *make depend* the following error appears:

```
make -C manifest
make[1]: Entering directory /home/osboxes/dev/mirage-stats-demo/manifest'
ocamlbuild manifest.native -pkgs unix,bytes,mirage
+ /usr/bin/ocamlc.opt -c -I /home/osboxes/.opam/system/lib/bytes -I
/home/osboxes/.opam/system/lib/cmdliner -I/home/osboxes/.opam/system/lib/fmt -I       /home/osboxes/.opam/system/lib/functoria -I /home/osboxes/.opam/system/lib/ipaddr -I /home/osboxes/.opam/system/lib/mirage -I /home/osboxes/.opam/system/lib/ocamlgraph -I /home/osboxes/.opam/system/lib/result -I /home/osboxes/.opam/system/lib/rresult -I /home/osboxes/.opam/system/lib/sexplib -I /usr/lib/ocaml -o manifest.cmo manifest.ml
File "manifest.ml", line 187, characters 12-23:
Error: Unbound value Mirage.load
Command exited with code 2.
Hint: Recursive traversal of subdirectories was not enabled for this build,
  as the working directory does not look like an ocamlbuild project (no
  '_tags' or 'myocamlbuild.ml' file). If you have modules in subdirectories,
  you should add the option "-r" or create an empty '_tags' file.

  To enable recursive traversal for some subdirectories only, you can use the
      following '_tags' file:
   true: -traverse
  <dir1> or <dir2>: traverse

Compilation unsuccessful after building 2 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:01.
make[1]: *** [all] Error 10
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/osboxes/dev/mirage-stats-demo/manifest'
make: *** [manifest/manifest.native] Error 2
```

Comment: I think that github's bug tracking page of corresponding project is a better place to report such issues

Comment: I do not have any issue with ubuntu 15.04 (ocaml 4.03.1) & 12.04 (ocaml 4.02.1). which version of ocaml are you using ? (not sure this can help).

Comment: You do not use an ocaml compiler installed by opam - I already observed some weird things when thre is a mix of native install & opam.

Comment: I've posted the bug on the project's github page and I found the answer I was looking for. For anyone interested : https://github.com/MagnusS/mirage-stats-demo/issues/5#issuecomment-172034339